# Error when try adding admob to the project

Tags: xamarin.android

I got this error when adding admob to the project.

[full project link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=178_N39UsJraOD2zzUw2xcpdTmTzi-gW7)

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error       error: MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method zzc(Bundle) in MediationRewardedVideoAdListener
public class MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor    app\App8\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\ads\reward\mediation\MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor.java 4
```

Comment: I can not download your project because it shows some danger, so can you take a look the Admob sample:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/google-services-admobexample/, if you still have some problem, please upload your sample at github.

Comment: thanks  Cherry Bu - MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Cherry Bu - MSFT

The cause of the problem occurred using an old version of Google’s advertising libraries

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.